# ¿Cómo obtener atributos del tema actual en Android?

Tags: java, android

Cómo se puede obtener atributos del tema establecido definidos dentro `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.Theme1">
   <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

Extraer el valor de `android:textColorPrimary` es decir que devuelve `0x00FF00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me permito hacer una traducción de [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952929/4987172):

Definir algún style arbitrario en `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Theme1">
    <item name="android:textColor">#efefef</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:text">This is my text</item>
</style>
```

Obtener los atributos de esta forma:

```java
// Los atributos que quieres obtener
int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.textColor, android.R.attr.background, android.R.attr.text};

// Convertir, usando Context.obtainStyledAttributes()
TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppTheme.Theme1, attrs);

// Obtener el texto de su estilo como este.     
String text = ta.getString(2);

// Obtener colores definidos en el style
int textColor = ta.getColor(0, Color.BLACK);
int backgroundColor = ta.getColor(1, Color.BLACK);

Log.i("Retrieved text:", text);
Log.i("Retrieved textColor as hex:", Integer.toHexString(textColor));
Log.i("Retrieved background as hex:", Integer.toHexString(backgroundColor));

// no olvidar reciclar el TypedArray
ta.recycle();
```

** Actualizacion **

Según la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html): el método `obtainStyledAttributes()` recibe los siguientes parámetros:

```
obtainStyledAttributes(int resId, int[] attrs)
```

por lo tanto, si queremos obtener los atributos del tema actual(cualquiera que este sea) solo debemos obtener el id del tema actual:

```
public int getThemeId() {
    try {
        Class<?> wrapper = Context.class;
        Method method = wrapper.getMethod("getThemeResId");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return (Integer) method.invoke(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Entonces, cambiamos la linea:

```
// Convertir, usando Context.obtainStyledAttributes()
TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppTheme.Theme1, attrs);
```

a:

```
// Convertir, usando Context.obtainStyledAttributes()
TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(getThemeId(), attrs);
```

Comment: Veo que esa solución seria para obtener los valores idependientemente del tema, no ser si hay algo más directo, que idependiente del nombre del tema, es decir el que este definido en la app actualmente, se extraiga sus valores.